# Parse : PFUser.enableAutomaticUser does not create user

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

When my app starts, I'm calling:

```
PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()
```

which, according to the documentation, will cause PFUser.currentUser() to always return a user.  It doesn't.  Subsequent calls yield nil. I've tried calling PFUser.enableAutomaticUser() immediately before returning currentUser(), but still have the same problem.

I'm compiling with Parse version 1.11.0 and running under iOS 9.2.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too faced same problem. I fixed the issue by calling `PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()`  , only after Parse ApplicationID is set

```
Parse.setApplicationId(parseApplicationID, clientKey:parseClientKey)
PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()
```